# Where does this series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Let $ \{r_1, r_2 ,r_3,... \}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $r_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ define:

$$u_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1/{2^n} & x>r_n \\ 0 & x \leq r_n \end{cases} $$

and let $$h (x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} u_n (x) $$ Where does this function converge to?

I know that $|u_n (x)| \leq 1/2^n$ and thus by the M-test the series converges uniformly but although it might be trivial I cannot see where. Is it something I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, $h$ is a strictly monotonic function that has discontinuities in all rational numbers and is continuous everywhere else. Also $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}h(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}h(x) = 1$.

Comment: And the rest depends on the choice of the enumeration hence, apart from that, not much can be said.

Comment: Right, thank you both @DanielFischer